# Can only vote 38 times in a day

Tags: support

I'm trying to get the badge where you vote 40 times a day, and I'm abruptly stopped at 38 votes, where I'm told that I can't vote anymore today; I'm really frustrated, because that means I have to wait until tomorrow, when my counter resets back to 0. Any ideas?

Comment: My voting stopped today after only 37 votes. I should point out that a few votes turned -1 votes into 0 for question posters.